# Ninject WCF extension does not work in MVC3 Ninject Website

Tags: wcf, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

We need to add a service to our website, I've added the MVC extension and added

```
Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"
```

To the markup, i've also added

```
KernelContainer.Kernel = kernel;
```

To the CreateKernel method to get rid of the root null problem, but now I get

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it
>   does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the
>   problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of
>   the type to the host.

The type in the constructor is binded in the kernel

Thanks

edit: This works

```
kernel.Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Ninject 3.0.0-rc2 available from Nuget. The new WCF and MVC extensions allow to run side a side.